# Something weird happening in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

So I started implementing a graph in c++. A graph has edges - a source node - a destination node (if its directed)

So I made a struct

```
struct Edge {
   int src, destin;

};
```

later though I decided to change the Edge struct to strings

```
struct Edge {
   string src, destin;
};
```

after I did this though I unable to assign these variables to strings.

in my main() function I have

```
#include "graph.h"
int main() {

    Edge e;
    //e.src = 0 // use to be this
    e.src = "P2" //this is an assignemnt error. it wants an int and is getting a char[3]

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Xcode expects an int but it should be a string]

HERE IS ALL OF THE CODE:

```
#include "graph.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    int num_p;
    int num_r;
    vector<int> num_of_units;


    Edge e;

    vector<Edge> edges;


    e.src = "P2";







//    e.src = 0;
//    e.destin = 29;
//    edges.push_back(e);



    return 0;

}
```

Graph.h below

```
#ifndef graph_h
#define graph_h

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


struct Edge {
    string src;
    string destin;
};


class Graph {

public:
    //adj matrix
    vector<vector<string > >adjL;






    //constructor
    Graph(vector<Edge> edges, int n){


        adjL.resize(n);


//        adjL.push_back(edges);

        //adding edges
        for(int i = 0; i < edges.size(); i++)
        {
            vector<string> temp;
            temp.push_back(edges[i].src);
            temp.push_back(edges[i].destin);
            adjL.push_back(temp);
        }



    }




};


void printG(Graph graph, int n);







#endif
```

Things I've tried already:
    - Clean
    - Restarting Xcode
    - Restarting Mac

EDIT: 
I think that I figured it out!
basically I started coding this from vim. I decided later after I had a few files created that I wanted to switch to an IDE aka Xcode. When I went to add all of the files some of them were referenced where the old ones were and some were created for the xcode project. so I would change the code in a file that was in xcode but I wasn't changing the file that xcode would actually use to run. it would use the other file with the same name.

Comment: Does it compile?

Comment: @anastaciu I've tried to compile his main code of assignment, the compiler throws an error of conversion failure.

Comment: @LinuXMan, I compile it fine, only trivial warnings like unused variables and differebt signedness coparison as you can see here https://wandbox.org/permlink/Mu2WaSYGFcOmqlnK

Comment: @anastaciu that's because line no. 61, 62, 63 are commented, remove the comments and see ;-)

Comment: @LinuXMan, yes but that is supposed to fail since `src` and `destin` were changed to string types, the issue on the question is the problem with assigning a string to `src` it being a string variable, I quote "later though I decided to change the Edge struct to strings ... e.src = "P2" //this is an assignemnt error. it wants an int and is getting a char[3". What I am trying to find out is if this is a compiler error or an error of VS Code auto-complete plugin. In the image, if src and destin are strings they are still perceived as ints by the IDE.

Comment: Im just using vim now because I was too frustrated with it finished my project now. just dumb that xcode has that implementation. I don't think its intintional but it has files created but are also referenced at the same time so it kinda "chooses" which one it should compile. At least this is what I think is going on since when I was testing I found out that it was printing a cout that I had created earlier in vim, but had deleted in xcode.

Comment: graph.h and Graph.h are different files.

Comment: thats a typo there is no difference in declaration of the filename

Answer (score 0):

Re-declaration of the same names for different data types **in the same scope** isn't allowed in C++. You can use the class with constructor overloading and get your wanted results. Look at the following:

```
#include <iostream>

class Edges
{
    std::string src, destin;
    int srcInt, destinInt;

public:
    Edges(std::string s1, std::string s2)
    {
        src = s1;
        destin = s2;

        std::cout << "src: " << src << " destin: " << destin << std::endl;
    }
    Edges(int s1, int s2)
    {
        srcInt = s1;
        destinInt = s2;

        std::cout << "src: " << srcInt << " destin: " << destinInt << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    Edges e0(123, 321);
    Edges e1("hello", "world");

    return 0;
}
```

> **Output:**

```
src: 123 destin: 321
src: hello destin: world
```

I hope it helps you.